# Is there a difference between getContext of Fragment and getContext of container passed to onCreateView of Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view, android-context

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Say if we call

`fragment.getContext()` and `container.getContext` will we get same result, the host activity?

Also does `view.getContext()` always returns `Activity` `context` or can it return some other kind of `context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Activity class in android extends Context class. So basically an activity is a context. But a context may not be an activity.

`fragment.getContext()` will return context of the container it is attached to. So yes `container.getContext()` will have the same results as of `fragment.getContext()` ie., the host activity.

> When instance of the ViewGroup is created, the inflater pass context of that activity to it. Means `container.getContext()` will return that same context.

`fragment.getActivity()` will return an activity it is attached with which is again a context. When the fragment is detached from the activity, it returns null. And when attached it also returns same as `getContext()`

And about your last question, `view.getContext()` returns context in which it is running. View doesnt extend Context class, infact when they are created, they require context object as parameter. So when you are creating a View inside a activty, you need to pass Context. And when you you call `view.getContext()`, you will get the same context back which you passed when you created it.

Comment: so we can pass `Application context` to view while its creation?

Comment: you can pass `getContext()` or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` when creating views in your app. but usually views are created in XML and inflater does the rest.

Comment: "So yes container.getContext() will have the same results as of fragment.getContext() ie., the host activity." But if `container` was inflated using `Application context`, we would have different context for `fragment.getcontext()` and `container.getContext`

Comment: I dont remember any case where a container will get inflated using `ApplicationContext`, A container must be tied to an activity and hence is inflated in a `ActivityContext`. `ApplicationContext` is Context of entire application and is tied with life Cycle of application which is different than that of an activity. You should not use `ApplicationContext` until you know what exactly you doing.

Comment: Yes, it is not used generally, but we can do so, the resulting `View` will not be themed, and will use system default `theme`

Comment: Approve my answer if u got the answer...@q126y